# libGDX Android using netbeans - task menu too big for screen

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

In the [libGDX netbeans run guide](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-and-NetBeans) it says to run on android, go `Tasks -> installDebug`. However in netbeans, the task menu is so long, installDebug does not show and one cannot scroll down the list. Someone else must have had this problem, but google has yielded no results to me. So my question is, how can i installDebug, do i have to create a custom task? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I'm sorry, but this is a reported bug marked as RESOLVED WONTFIX.

As Marian Mirilovic, NetBeans Quality Engineering Manager said in [Bug 242160](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=242160):

> No plans to change it
>
> NetBeans is a Swing application and Swing doesn't provide any scrolling menu functionality.

Comment: Thanks for finding the report, do you know of any solution to this issue?

Answer (score 5):

You can add "new" task too `Custom Task` list. 
Works nicely for often used tasks so you don't have too search on this long list.

In your case use "installDebug" as a name for custom task.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If someone wonders here out of frustration of not be able to run libgdx game from netbeans onto android device, you can try to change your screen orientation to *portrait*. This should show a bit bigger tasks' list and probably you will be able to run "InstallDebug". On Windows usually it's done by opening screen resolution from Control Panel and changing Orientation preference.

It doesn't solve the problem, but at least there is a possibility that you will be able to run "Tasks -> installDebug" in Netbeans. As this is need to be done once, after that you can change back screen orientation and work on.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: How this does not provide an answer if it helped solve exact problem for me?

Comment: Sometimes there are no solutions that solve the entire issue, workarounds should **not** be downvoted!